# Apex Generation Failed - WSDL problem - SOAP

Tags: soap-api, xml, wsdl, wsdl2apex, developer

I'm trying to solve this problem with Salesforce.

I'm trying to generate apex classes from WSDL (converted from WADL)

Parsing works correcly without any errors and warning. But I can't generate the apex code from WSDL.

Step 1

[image]

Step 2 with error

[image]

WSDL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" targetNamespace="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xs:simpleType name="orderby">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="time" />
              <xs:enumeration value="time-asc" />
              <xs:enumeration value="magnitude" />
              <xs:enumeration value="magnitude-asc" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType name="format">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="quakeml" />
              <xs:enumeration value="csv" />
              <xs:enumeration value="geojson" />
              <xs:enumeration value="kml" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType name="kmlcolorby">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="age" />
              <xs:enumeration value="depth" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType name="reviewstatus">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="automatic" />
              <xs:enumeration value="reviewed" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:simpleType name="producttype">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="moment-tensor" />
              <xs:enumeration value="focal-mechanism" />
              <xs:enumeration value="shakemap" />
              <xs:enumeration value="losspager" />
              <xs:enumeration value="dyfi" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:element name="GET_version_InputMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GET_version_OutputMessage" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="GET_catalogs_InputMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GET_catalogs_OutputMessage" type="xs:anyType" />
          <xs:element name="GET_contributors_InputMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GET_contributors_OutputMessage" type="xs:anyType" />
          <xs:element name="GET_application.wadl_InputMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GET_application.wadl_OutputMessage" type="xs:anyType" />
          <xs:element name="GET_query_InputMessage">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="starttime" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endtime" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="updatedafter" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="-90" name="minlatitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="90" name="maxlatitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="-180" name="minlongitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="0" name="latitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="0" name="longitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="0" name="minradius" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="180" name="maxradius" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mindepth" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxdepth" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="minmagnitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxmagnitude" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="magnitudetype" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="includeallmagnitudes" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="includeallorigins" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="includearrivals" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="eventid" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="limit" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="1" name="offset" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="time" name="orderby" type="tns:orderby" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="contributor" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="catalog" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="quakeml" name="format" type="tns:format" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="callback" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="age" name="kmlcolorby" type="tns:kmlcolorby" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="false" name="kmlanimated" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="eventtype" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reviewstatus" type="tns:reviewstatus" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="minmmi" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxmmi" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mincdi" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxcdi" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="minfelt" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" default="*" name="alertlevel" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mingap" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxgap" type="xs:double" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="minsig" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="maxsig" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="producttype" type="tns:producttype" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="GET_query_OutputMessage" type="xs:anyType" />
        </xs:schema>
      </types>
      <message name="GET_version_InputMessage">
        <part name="GET_version_InputMessage" xmlns:q1="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q1:GET_version_InputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_version_OutputMessage">
        <part name="GET_version_OutputMessage" xmlns:q2="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q2:GET_version_OutputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_catalogs_InputMessage">
        <part name="GET_catalogs_InputMessage" xmlns:q3="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q3:GET_catalogs_InputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_catalogs_OutputMessage">
        <part name="GET_catalogs_OutputMessage" xmlns:q4="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q4:GET_catalogs_OutputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_contributors_InputMessage">
        <part name="GET_contributors_InputMessage" xmlns:q5="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q5:GET_contributors_InputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_contributors_OutputMessage">
        <part name="GET_contributors_OutputMessage" xmlns:q6="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q6:GET_contributors_OutputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_application.wadl_InputMessage">
        <part name="GET_application.wadl_InputMessage" xmlns:q7="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q7:GET_application.wadl_InputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_application.wadl_OutputMessage">
        <part name="GET_application.wadl_OutputMessage" xmlns:q8="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q8:GET_application.wadl_OutputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_query_InputMessage">
        <part name="GET_query_InputMessage" xmlns:q9="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q9:GET_query_InputMessage" />
      </message>
      <message name="GET_query_OutputMessage">
        <part name="GET_query_OutputMessage" xmlns:q10="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/schemas" element="q10:GET_query_OutputMessage" />
      </message>
      <portType name="API_PortType">
        <operation name="GET_version">
          <documentation></documentation>
          <input xmlns:q11="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q11:GET_version_InputMessage" />
          <output xmlns:q12="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q12:GET_version_OutputMessage">
            <documentation></documentation>
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_catalogs">
          <documentation></documentation>
          <input xmlns:q13="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q13:GET_catalogs_InputMessage" />
          <output xmlns:q14="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q14:GET_catalogs_OutputMessage">
            <documentation></documentation>
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_contributors">
          <documentation></documentation>
          <input xmlns:q15="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q15:GET_contributors_InputMessage" />
          <output xmlns:q16="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q16:GET_contributors_OutputMessage">
            <documentation></documentation>
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_application.wadl">
          <documentation></documentation>
          <input xmlns:q17="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q17:GET_application.wadl_InputMessage" />
          <output xmlns:q18="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q18:GET_application.wadl_OutputMessage">
            <documentation></documentation>
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_query">
          <documentation></documentation>
          <input xmlns:q19="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q19:GET_query_InputMessage" />
          <output xmlns:q20="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" message="q20:GET_query_OutputMessage">
            <documentation></documentation>
          </output>
        </operation>
      </portType>
      <binding name="API_Binding" xmlns:q21="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" type="q21:API_PortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
        <operation name="GET_version">
          <soap:operation soapAction="GET_version" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_catalogs">
          <soap:operation soapAction="GET_catalogs" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_contributors">
          <soap:operation soapAction="GET_contributors" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_application.wadl">
          <soap:operation soapAction="GET_application.wadl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GET_query">
          <soap:operation soapAction="GET_query" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </input>
          <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
          </output>
        </operation>
      </binding>
      <service name="API">
        <documentation></documentation>
        <port name="default_Port" xmlns:q22="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/wsdl" binding="q22:API_Binding">
          <soap:address location="https%3A%2F%2Fearthquake.usgs.gov%2Ffdsnws%2Fevent%2F1%2F" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" />
        </port>
      </service>
    </definitions>
```

Thanks in advice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the API you are using is the [USGS Earthquake Catalog](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/). It appears their WADL is for describing a REST based web service rather than one that is SOAP based.

The Salesforce WSDL2Apex tooling won't really help you here as it is all based around SOAP based services.

Salesforce also has JSON support, so if you calls using the `format=geojson` query string parameter is should be fairly straight forward to parse the json response.

E.g. sent a `GET` request to https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02 then use and Apex [JSONParser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsonparser.htm) to parse it.

There are even tools available that will generate Apex classes based on the structure of the JSON response. See [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/)